# add an image and it span in multiple pages using itextsharp

Tags: .net, image, itext

How can I add a large image, that spans over in multiple PDF pages using iTextSharp. I have an image that exceeds the PDF page height and because of it, the image is not fully displaying in the PDF page. Image's last portion is missing.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849715/itext-swing-component-to-more-then-one-page/20851964#20851964) shows how to show different parts of a template on different document pages in iText/Java. You need to do the equivalent in iTextSharp/.Net for a template wrapping your image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if this solves your issue:

```
Document oDocument = new Document();
oDocument.Open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.WidthPercentage = 100;
PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell(image, true);
c.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
c.Padding = 5;
c.Image.ScaleToFit(750f,750f); /*The new line*/
table.AddCell(c);  // <-- Add the cell to the table
oDocument.Add(table);
```

I hope using `PDfPTable`  will probably solve your issue.