# C# itextsharp adding image to pdf and extend to multiple pages

Tags: c#, wpf, itext, screenshot

[image]

this is the image I am testing

I have a window which is greater than one page, I will screenshot that via programmatically then pass that image to pdf, my problem is that it is not extending into 2 or more pages, how do I do that using itextsharp?

and is there a better to screenshot my image? the resolutions seems bad...

here are the codes...

---

```
        String imageFileName = "ScreenCapture" + ".png";
        String pdfFileName = "PurchaseOrder" + ".pdf";

        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(2550, 3300, 100, 100, PixelFormats.Default);
        renderTargetBitmap.Render(this);
        PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));

        using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(saveWhere + imageFileName))
        {
            pngImage.Save(fileStream);
        }
```

---

As you can see, I also have a problem screenshotting it, it seems that it is giving me too much whitespace instead of screenshotting the whole wpf window....

Tried the possible answer but no it does not extend the pages...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add an image and it span in multiple pages using itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829386/add-an-image-and-it-span-in-multiple-pages-using-itextsharp)

Comment: @Rekshino I just tried this, doesn't extend it into multiple pages...

Comment: Can you show adjusted code? It seems the answer has helped OP and he has asked the same.