# How to draw a large shape in a PDF and have it span multiple pages

Tags: itext

I am drawing a shape with iTextSharp that is very big. How do I get the shape to span multiple pages?

```
string pdfpath = Server.MapPath("PDFs");        
Document doc = new Document();  
doc.NewPage();  
doc.AddTitle("");
doc.AddAuthor("");       
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfpath + "/Graphics.pdf",Mode.Create));           
doc.Open();        
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;            
cb.MoveTo(570f, 20f);        
cb.LineTo(570f, 3324);         

cb.MoveTo(570f, 20f);
cb.LineTo(570f, 3324);
cb.ClosePath();
cb.Stroke();

cb.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.GREEN);

//start point (x,y)
//Start Point

cb.MoveTo(450f, 70f);

//Control Point 1, Control Point 2, End Point

cb.Circle(450f, 70f, 30f);

cb.Stroke();
doc.Close();
```

Comment: I just increasing the page size an option?

Comment: Alternatively draw on a generic PdfTemplate and include different sections of that as xobjects on different pages

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [What's an easy to print "first right, then down"?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/whats-easy-print-first-right-then-down) That question is about distributing a large table over different pages, but the concept is identical: as indicated by @mkl, you need to use a `PdfTemplate` and distribute that *Form XObject* over different pages (e.g. first right, then down).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iText swing component to more then one page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849715/itext-swing-component-to-more-then-one-page). @user3608913 Simply ignore that the `PdfTemplate` there is filled from a Java graphics context and instead draw on it like you draw on `cb` in your code. And the transition to C#/iTextSharp is trivial.

Comment: I thought this was a duplicate of [add an image and it span in multiple pages using itextsharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829386/add-an-image-and-it-span-in-multiple-pages-using-itextsharp) but then I saw that you were drawing your shape instead of inserting an image.